# Somar colunas de uma tabela em um campo total e repetir a soma a cada nova linha

Tags: php, javascript

tenho uma tabela com algumas colunas para digitação de valores e preciso somar o total desses valores numa coluna final.

A soma está facil de fazer, no entanto a tabela e dinamica e são gerados 
varias linhas, e quando tento somar novamente as colunas na nova linha, estou somando também o resultado das linhas anteriores.

Acredito que devo ter que definir a minha chamada em javascript como default para a nova linha de calculo mas nao to sabendo fazer
vejam o exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que na primeira coluna o total soma corretamente, na segunda ele soma certo tbm, mas acrescenta o valor junto com o resultado do campo anterior.

O codigo PHP esta assim:

```
<?php for ($cont = 1; $cont <= $quantidadeRegistros; $cont++): ?> 
<tr>
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++): ?>
        <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='text' name='quantidade[]' onkeyup='calcular(<?php echo $cont ?>)' </td>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <td>
        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='total[]' id='result-<?php echo $cont ?>' readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

E o javascript assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 function calcular(id) {
        var campo = 'result-'.concat(id);
        var soma = $('.calcular').get().reduce(function (soma, el) {
            return (parseInt(el.value, 10) || 0) + soma;
        }, 0);
        document.getElementById(campo).value = soma;
    }
});
```

Acho que se definir que a cada linha a soma deve ser começada do zero eu resolvo o problema, mas nao identifiquei como fazer isso

Comment: Em que momento a função calcular é chamada?

Comment: quando digito um valor dentro do input dos produtos. No input tem uma chamada onkeyup='calcular(<?php echo $cont ?>)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O truque aqui para não somar com os da linha anterior está nesta linha `$(this).parents('tr').find('input.calcular')` em que vamos "perguntar ao elemento pai, `tr` (linha), quais os valores dos filhos com a class `calcular`, ou seja, só os valores dos inputs filhos dessa linha (`tr`) com a class calcular é que são contabilizados para esse calculo.

Alterando um bocadinho a tua estrutura, mas crieio que o resultado que queres é este:

```js
$('.calcular').on('keyup change', function() {
 var total = 0;
 $(this).parents('tr').find('input.calcular').each(function(){
  var val = parseInt($(this).val());
  if(!isNaN(val)) {
   total += parseInt(val);
  }
 });
 $(this).parents('tr').find('input.total').val(total);
});
```

```css
input {
 width: 70px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='number' name='quantidade[]'</td>
  <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='number' name='quantidade[]'</td>
  <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='number' name='quantidade[]'</td>
  <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='number' name='quantidade[]'</td>
  <td><input class='form-control total' type='text' name='total[]' id='result-1' readonly /></td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr>
  <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='number' name='quantidade[]'</td>
  <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='number' name='quantidade[]'</td>
  <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='number' name='quantidade[]'</td>
  <td><input class='form-control calcular' type='number' name='quantidade[]'</td>
  <td><input class='form-control total' type='text' name='total[]' id='result-2' readonly /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Reduzi os inputs para que ficassem todos vizíveis, também os mudei para `type=number`

Comment: Miguel, sensacional mais uma vez meu caro. Poderia me explicar como funciona a logica de nao somar com o resultado da linha anterior?

Comment: @tkmattos vou acresentar essa explicação na resposta

Comment: blz, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: De nada @tkmattos, já acrescentei se não perceber diga que tento explicar melhor. Bom Ano